# npm ERR! extraneous: pug@2.0.0-alpha6

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, coffeescript

I need some help. I am just learning to build a website with node.js.
I have installed node v4.5.0, npm 2.15.9, coffeescript 1.10.0
I am following instructions from a book "CoffeeScript and Node.js".
I have this file `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "todo",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "3.0.0beta6",
        "jade": "*",
        "socket.io": "*",
        "coffee-script": "*",
        "connect-assets": "*"
    }
}
```

I ran the command: `npm install`, after which some warnings were shown, about `jade` being deprecated, and that `pug` had to be installed.
I have changed `jade` to `pug` in the `package.json` file, and ran `npm install` again. And again there were some warnings, about newer versions of `pug`! Made some changes again, at last this ERR appeared!
I would appreciate some help, how to go on.

Note: *the example code is from quite an old book (2012), and never updated*
How should I proceed? I have a directory tree with both `jade` *and* `pug`. Will that work? Or should I update `node` and/or `npm`?

EDIT: I got most of it working now, but another issue came up. Should it be related to the previous ones?
The issue: I installed another helper module: `npm install supervisor -g`. When I run `supervisor app.coffee`, at first everything looks right, but after making changes in one of the files, the console display goes wild. I have to stop it, and this is what came out:

```
Starting child process with 'coffee.cmd app.coffee'
Listening on port 3000
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
  at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
  at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
  at Server._listen2 (net.js:1250:14)
  at listen (net.js:1286:10)
  at Server.listen (net.js:1382:5)
  at Function.app.listen (C:\Examples\todo_node\todo\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:533:24)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Examples\todo_node\todo\app.coffee:13:5)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Examples\todo_node\todo\app.coffee:1:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
  at Object.exports.run (C:\Users\ad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\coffee-script.js:134:23)
  at compileScript (C:\Users\ad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\command.js:224:29)
  at compilePath (C:\Users\ad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\command.js:174:14)
  at Object.exports.run (C:\Users\ad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\command.js:98:20)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\bin\coffee:7:41)
  at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
  at startup (node.js:139:18)
  at node.js:974:3

 Program coffee.cmd app.coffee exited with code 1

Starting child process with 'coffee.cmd app.coffee'
Received SIGINT, killing child process...
Parent process exiting, terminating child...
```

Second EDIT; I have read that `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000` is indicating that the 3000 address is in use. I have no idea what might be using it, but rather I'd like to know how this can be avoided. I am running this app on Windows 10, that just had an update today.
And, moreover, I have no problems running the app with the command `coffee app.coffee`. Drawback is that this has to be closed and started again each time a file is changed.

I hope someone can help me further,

Thank you,
Ad

Comment: Well about your second issue, open a windows console with administrator status and use "netstat -bano". Search for the port 3000 and you will see the process which uses the port.
About the first issue don't forget to mark as answered when it's done, and open a second post to describes just the second issue (cause I didn't see your edit since now).

Answer (score 1):

Jade is the old name of the Pug templating engine.
Use Pug, latest version is 2.0.0-b6 :
[Pug page on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug)

You can try it on the page, in your browser.
If NPM fails, try [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pugjs/pug)

If you aren't comfortable with versions, just use :

```
npm install pug --save
```

To automatically add Pug into your package.json (with the correct, latest version).

Edit : which warnings/errors do you have ? Can you post it please ?
Edit 2 : your Express version is outdated too.